# find the values of the constants where the function is continuous, but not differentiable.

Tags: calculus, functions

For the following function, find the values of the constants $a$ and $b$ for which the function is continuous, but not differentiable.

$f(x)=ax+b, x>0$

$f(x)=\sin x, x \leq 0$

I ve found out, that it is differentiable at $a=1$ and $b=0 $ 
Hope, it's correct.

But now, how to find out where it is not differentiable?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! It would be helpful if you included the work you have done yourself. That helps other people to see where your problems lie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lim x goes to 0 cos x -> 1 and a ->a so a must be 1 and it isnt differntiable if a is not 1

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

The function is differentiable at a constant $c$ iff the two limits $\lim_{x\rightarrow c-}\frac{f\left(x\right)-f\left(c\right)}{x-c}$
and $\lim_{x\rightarrow c+}\frac{f\left(x\right)-f\left(c\right)}{x-c}$
both exist and coincide.

Apply that here on $c=0$.